# Sum of All Related Rows with Matching ID MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table schema:

```
    tbl_portfolio
    ----------
    id (auto number)
    name
```

-

```
    tbl_registration
    ----------------
    id(auto number)
    name
    portfolio_id (FK to tbl_portfolio.id)
```

-

```
    tbl_fund
    ---------
    id (auto number)
    registration_id (FK to tbl_registration.id)
```

-

```
     tbl_transaction
     ---------------
     id (auto number)
     fund_id (FK to tbl_fund.id)
     type
     shares
     price
```

I need to create a query that in psuedo-code would do the following:

```
      SELECT port.*, SUM ALL transactions for each portfolio,
      FROM tbl_portfolio port
      INNER JOIN tbl_registration reg ON reg.portfolio_id = port.id
      LEFT JOIN tbl_fund fund on fund.registration_id = reg.id
      LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction trans ON trans.fund_id = fund.id
```

Now of course that query won't work...What I am needing essentially is to sum all the **Price * Units** for each fund, and then sum those together for each registration, and then sum all of that together for each portfolio.

Each portfolio can have multiple registrations, and each registration can have multiple funds, and each fund can have multiple transactions.

The last item that is throwing a stickler in this, there may be 10's or 100's of portfolios to count so I have no idea how to write the query, much less write it in an effective way that is not relying on subqueries that would cause it to have severely poor performance.

Thank you for the help!

Edit:
PinnyM's answer works and queries the data correctly - however I should expand on the full need.

Besides the tbl_transaction there is also a tbl_distri and tbl_div. Both have fund_id as FK to tbl_fund.id . I need to get the SUM's of tbl_distri.amount and tbl_div.units.
So the full psuedo query would be something to the effect of:

```
      SELECT port.*, SUM ALL transactions for each portfolio, SUM(div.units), SUM(distri.amount)
      FROM tbl_portfolio port
      INNER JOIN tbl_registration reg ON reg.portfolio_id = port.id
      LEFT JOIN tbl_fund fund on fund.registration_id = reg.id
      LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction trans ON trans.fund_id = fund.id
      LEFT JOIN tbl_distri distri on distri.fund_id = fund.id
      LEFT JOIN tbl_div div on div.fund_id = fund.id
```

Comment: ... I'm assuming `tbl_fund` has more columns in it, or what's the point?  Also, why put the `tbl_...` prefix on everything - it's just so much noise.

Comment: Do you need to sum the number of shares, or the prices, or what? That is, what do you mean by "sum all the transactions"?

Comment: If a portfolio can have multiple registrations, then your join from tbl_portfolio to tbl_registration will need to be a LEFT JOIN too.

Comment: Clockwork, tbl_fund does have more columns - just those necessary are shown. And tbl_ is because of shared hosting requirements.
Melanie, need the sum of Shares * Price
EvilBob, if a portfolio does not have any registrations and a LEFT JOIN is used the portfolio will still show in the query results correct? With null for a SUM value

Question text updated

Comment: Yes, if you do portfolio left join registration, you will get portfolios with no registrations.  Using an inner join, you will only get portfolios with registrations.  If you want to exclude the ones with no registrations, include `WHERE reg.portfolio_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Evilbob is that more performant then an inner join?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `SUM()`?

```
SELECT port.*, SUM(trans.shares * trans.price) AS transaction_totals
  FROM tbl_portfolio port
  INNER JOIN tbl_registration reg ON reg.portfolio_id = port.id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_fund fund on fund.registration_id = reg.id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction trans ON trans.fund_id = fund.id
  GROUP BY port.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, you are looking for a rolled-up SUM

```
       SELECT port.id AS port_id, 
              reg.id  AS reg_id, 
              fund.id AS fund_id,
              SUM ( trans.shares * trans.price) AS net_asset_value
         FROM tbl_portfolio port
   INNER JOIN tbl_registration reg ON reg.portfolio_id = port.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_fund fund on fund.registration_id = reg.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction trans ON trans.fund_id = fund.id
     GROUP BY port.id, reg.id, fund.id WITH ROLLUP
```

This will give you the sums id by id.  You can use other JOIN operations with this as a subquery to fetch the textual names.

This will give results like this:

```
 port_id  reg_id  fund_id   net_asset_value
    1       1       1          150.00
    1       1       2          100.00
    1       1      NULL        250.00   (rollup of previous two lines)
    1       2       1           24.00
    1       2       4           80.00
    1       2      NULL        104.00   (rollup of previous two lines)
    1      NULL    NULL        354.00   (rollup at portfolio level)
    3       1       1           40.00
    3       1       2           50.00
    3       1      NULL         90.00   (rollup of previous two lines)
    3       2       1           14.00
    3       2       4           60.00
    3       2      NULL         74.00   (rollup of previous two lines)
    3      NULL    NULL        164.00   (rollup at portfolio level)
  NULL     NULL    NULL        518.00   (grand total)
```

The NULLs make it into this resultset because that's what WITH ROLLUP does. This resultset only has the IDs in it; presumably the IDs are unique even if the names aren't. Non-unique names for portfolios, funds, etc, will mess up the GROUP BY pretty badly. Hence my earlier comment about retrieving the names.

Comment: Ollie, I believe I'm confused by your last comment. The query above is returning the sum of each fund, and its associated fund id, reg id, and port id. If I am wanting to sum all of that together and return it for each portfolio_id what are you suggesting?

Comment: Ollie, thank you for the expanded edit! So, if this query result is being loaded into a table with PHP how do you display the rollup ONLY and not the subsequent values that lead up to the rollup? And is this more efficient then summing the data directly (i.e. without the rollup)

Comment: It's not clear from your question at what levels you want your sums rolled up.  Can you clarify?